# DataTable column is showing object and not displaying actually value?

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables, phalcon

I am trying to populate DataTable with my Data but DataTable is showing **object** in columns and not printing the actual values!

[image]

Function in Controller:

```
public function getEvaluationSymptomsAction() {

        //Get Evaluation Symptoms from DataBase
        $evaluation_symptoms = CxEbEvaluationSymptom::getAllEvaluationSymptomsWithNameForDataTable();

        $inferredRemedies = array();

        $additonalRemedies = array();

        $data = array();

        foreach ($evaluation_symptoms as $key => $symptom) {
            $data[ $key ][ 'id' ] = $symptom[ 'id' ];
            $data[ $key ][ 'title' ] = $symptom[ 'title' ];

            // Get Inferred Remedies By Symptom ID
            $inferredRemedies = CxEbEvaluationSymptom::getInferredRemediesBySymptomId($symptom[ 'id' ]);

            $additonalRemedies = CxEbEvaluationSymptom::getAdditionalSymptomRemediesBySymptomId($symptom[ 'id' ]);


            $data[ $key ][ 'remedy' ] = $inferredRemedies;


            $data[ $key ][ 'additional-remedy' ] = $additonalRemedies;


            $data[ $key ][ 'date_created' ] = $symptom[ 'date_created' ];

        }
//print_r($data);exit;
        // Return data array
        return array('data' => $data);
        // Return data
    }
```

The above function return the below array: (NOTE the below array is **var_dump** version actually data is in **JSON** format)

[Array code is here](https://pastebin.com/BZmNjwUN)

**Queries**:

```
public static function getInferredRemediesBySymptomId($symptomId){
        $queryBuilder = new Builder();

        return  $queryBuilder
            ->from(array('es' =>  'Cx\EbFront\Models\Evaluation\CxEbEvaluationSymptom'))
            ->leftJoin('Cx\EbFront\Models\Evaluation\CxEbEvaluationSymptomCause',  'es.id = esc.evaluation_symptom_id','esc')
            ->leftJoin('Cx\EbFront\Models\Evaluation\CxEbEvaluationCause','esc.evaluation_cause_id = ec.id','ec')
            ->leftJoin('Cx\EbFront\Models\Evaluation\CxEbEvaluationCauseRemedy','ec.id = ecr.evaluation_cause_id','ecr')
            ->leftJoin('Cx\EbFront\Models\Evaluation\CxEbEvaluationRemedy','ecr.evaluation_remedy_id = er.id', 'er')
            //->leftJoin('Cx\EbFront\Models\Evaluation\CxEbEvaluationSymptom', 'es.id = :ID:', 'es')
            ->columns('er.id, er.title')
            ->where('es.is_active = 1')
            ->andWhere('es.id = :ID:')
            ->getQuery()
            ->execute(array('ID' => $symptomId))
            //->execute()->setHydrateMode(Resultset::HYDRATE_ARRAYS)
            ->toArray();
    }

    /**
     * A
     * Data for column Additonal Remedies in DataTable
     * @return array
     */
    public static function getAdditionalSymptomRemediesBySymptomId($symptomId){
        $queryBuilder = new Builder();

        return  $queryBuilder
            ->from(array('er' =>  'Cx\EbFront\Models\Evaluation\CxEbEvaluationRemedy'))
            ->innerJoin('Cx\EbFront\Models\Evaluation\CxEbEvaluationSymptomRemedy',  'er.id = esr.evaluation_remedy_id','esr')
            ->columns('er.id, er.title')
            ->where('er.is_active = 1')
            ->andWhere('esr.evaluation_symptom_id = :ID:')
            ->getQuery()
            ->execute(array('ID' => $symptomId))
            ->toArray();
    }
```

The below is the JS code for initializing the DataTable:

```
function EbEvaluationSymptom(){
    var $body = $('body');
    var $CxRecordsTable = $('#cx-records-table');

    // Init the DatTable using the Cx Admin DataTable plugin
    cx.common.data.cxAdminDataTables.EbEvaluationSymptom = $CxRecordsTable.cxAdminDataTable({
        ajaxUrl: '<?php echo $this->CxHelper->Route('eb-admin-get-evaluation-symptoms')?>',
        columns: [
            cx.common.admin.tableEditColumn('id'),
            { data: 'title' },
            { data: 'remedy' },
            { data: 'additional-remedy' },
            { data: 'date_created' }

        ],

    });

};
```

JSON Response:

https://pastebin.com/g2mhhS4D

Comment: Post the JSON data which you are getting back from your Ajax request?

Comment: @UmairShahYousafzai updated the question buddy

Comment: It seems you are getting remedies data in objects what you need to do is make an array of them and then implode those into a string and then return it back then you won't be having this issue. But remember to only return the remedies and no id's.

Comment: These are arrays buddy not objects.

Comment: There is no array data type in JavaScript. Pretty much everything in JS is objects. It's called Array object :)

Comment: Check the following pen if you think that Array is not an object : https://codepen.io/idesi/pen/ZONYAW/

Comment: Check the following pen for your `[object object]` issue as well to understand that how it happens & why : https://codepen.io/idesi/pen/dpPkEq

Comment: When you are trying to access an object method or property & when it goes wrong i.e when you are calling it wrong or you are calling to an object as a property etc so instead by default `.toString()` method is called on the object which is the default prototype method which results in `[object object]`

Comment: Read this for the detailed difference between arrays vs objects in JavaScript : https://www.google.com.pk/amp/frontendmayhem.com/javascript-arrays-objects/amp/

Comment: And I was telling you to do that in PHP not in JS :) Because seems to be from your code that you are using PHP.

Answer (score 1):

DataTables doesn't know how to format the array of object(s) supplied for remedy & additional-remedy.
Assuming there is always one object in each of those arrays, you want to access the first object in each array and use its title property:

```
columns: [
    cx.common.admin.tableEditColumn('id'),
    { data: 'title' },
    { data: 'remedy.0.title' },
    { data: 'additional-remedy.0.title' },
    { data: 'date_created' }

],
```

If you plan to have more than 1 element in each array, you'll need a different approach